# Group element in NSMutableArray which contains object

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, union

I have an NSMutableArray that contains an object of a class model in each position like this.
The class model contains 2 types of information, which we will call **id** and **name**.
So, in every location of my NSMutableArray I have an object that contains 2 information.

Then, in the first position of my NSMutableArray I have

```
{
 id = 1;
 name = "Dan"; //this is the first object in NSMutableArray
}
```

In the second position of NSMutableArray, I have:

```
{
 id = 1;
 name = "Luca"; 
}
```

In the third position

```
{
 id = 2;
 name = "Tom"; 
}
```

and so on..

Ok, my goal is to make the union of identical IDs between the various objects within the SNMutableArray but it's too difficult!

For example, if I have:

```
{
 id = 1;
 name = "Tom"; 
}

{
 id = 1;
 name = "Luca"; 
}

{
 id = 2;
 name = "Steve"; 
}

{
 id = 2;
 name = "Jhon"; 
}

{
 id = 3;
 name = "Andrew"; 
}
```

The goal is:

```
{
 id = 1;
 name = "Tom"; 
 name = "Luca"; 
}
{
 id = 2;
 name = "Steve";
 name = "Jhon"; 

}
{
 id = 3;
 name = "Andrew"; 
}
```

Any ideas? would like to use this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method and I tried to write this: (cm is my class model and myArray is the NSMutableArray which contains an object of cm class)

```
ClassModel *cm = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


NSMutableArray * resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray * groups = [array valueForKeyPath:cm.ID];
for (NSString * groupId in groups)
{
     NSMutableDictionary * entry = [NSMutableDictionary new];
     [insert setObject: groupId forKey: @ "groupId"];

     NSArray * groupNames = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @ "groupId =% @", groupId]];
     for (int i = 0; i <groupNames.count; i ++)
     {
         NSString * name = [[groupNames objectAtIndex: i] objectForKey: @ "name"];
         [entry setObject: name forKey: [NSS string stringWithFormat: @ "name% d", i + 1]];
     }
     [resultArray addObject: entry];
}

NSLog (@ "% @", resultArray);
```

But this does not work..maybe because each element in my array is an object?? .. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right basic idea, but you shouldn't try and do this in `cellForRowAt`.  Rather, you need to create a new array that has the data in the required structure and use that array as the source for your tableview.  You will also need to create a new class to put in the array; one that has an `id` and an `NSMutableArray` for the names (I won't show this but I will call it `GroupClassModel`)

Use something like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *groups = [NSMutableDictionary new]
for (ClassModel *cm in array) {
    GroupClassModel *gcm = groups[cm.id];
    if (gcm == nil) {
        gcm = [GroupClassModel new];
        gcm.id = cm.id
        groups[cm.id] = gcm
    }
    [gcm.names addObject:cm.name];
}

NSArray *groupedName = [groups allValues];
// Finally, sort groupedName by id if that is required.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have only one question: what is  `GroupClassModel *gcm`? I do not understand

Comment: It is a new object class that you will need to create that has an array for names rather than a single string.

Comment: Ok, now I understand! Final question, if I would to replace id with a string for the union, does it work anyway? I have a warning `Instance method '-add:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

Comment: What is `gcm.names` in your case? It needs to be an `NSMutableArray`, otherwise you could create a method on your `GroupClassModel` `- void add[name: (NSString *)]` that hides the array detail and then you would say `[gcm add:cm.name]`

Comment: For simplicity, I put the question using ID as a reference. But actually grouping for a _string_ type field. In my cases, `gcm.names` is a NSMutableArray of names, string. And ID is a NSString in `gcm` class model!

Comment: The type of `id` doesn't matter for my code; it will work if `id` is an `NSString` as long as both `ClassModel.id` and `GroupClassModel.id` are declared as `NSString`.  Is `ClassModel.name` a string or an array?

Comment: `ClassModel.name` is a `NSString`..instead `GroupClassModel.name` is a NSMutableArray, because grouping by ID, I have more names, right?

Comment: But I don't understand why `instance method '-add:' not found` ☹️

Comment: Sorry, too much time in Swift away from Objective-C.  It should be `addObject`.

Comment: If it helps, here is gist with my [GroupClassModel](https://gist.github.com/paulw11/b192855bea5d260dfe75c22eec036130)

Comment: the only problem is on the line `[gcm.names addObject:cm.name];` because Xcode say: `'NSString' may not respond to 'addObject:'`

Comment: If you are using my class from the gist, you should be aware that it "hides" the underluying `NSMutableArray` and you need to call `[gcm addName:cm.name]`

Comment: Is the same, `Instance method '-addName:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')` 